# Create Center Aligned Button Menu For different Device Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a problem with this layout. I have a menu button with 6 item and I use a grid for it( I disable the scroll function). When I try it in my Poco F1, it place right in the center of the screen. But when I use a phone with bigger screen, the menu is slightly in the left side of the screen. Is there any way to make it in the center of the screen despite different screen size?

Here is the picture when using Pixel 3 XL

[image]

This is my code

```
 Widget _gridView (BuildContext context) {
    double cardWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2;
    double cardHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 31/100;
    return GridView.count(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        childAspectRatio: cardWidth / cardHeight,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        mainAxisSpacing: 5,
        crossAxisSpacing: 3,
        children: List.generate(6, (index) {
          return
            Center(
              child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child:
                  SizedBox(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: (){
                              if(index == 0)
                                Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new DoctorList()));
                              if(index == 1)
                                launchWhatsApp();
                              if(index == 2)
                                launchWhatsApp();
                              if(index == 5)
                                showMenu(context);
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              width: 80,
                              height: 80,
                              child: Image.asset(icons[index]),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 5,
                          ),
                          Text(teks[index], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize:14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
                        ],
                      )
                  )
              ),
            );
        })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use flutter screen util package and give dimension using it,
it will give dimension according to device aspect ratio